# Analyse Logdata out of a cvs file all written in a long row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, logging

I have a set of a couple hundreds sensors whose data is recorded in a log file. Each measurement cycle of all sensors is written in one line of the log file in cvs format. I need to be able to structure the log file to make some analysis with plots and calculations of the values.

The format of the CVS is like the following:

```
ID;Time;SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD;SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD[3..400]SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD
11234;11:12:123456;12345678;5.3;53.4;53;-36.6;72345670;5.8;57.4;56;-39.6;[...]92345670;5.9;60.4;55;-33.6;
```

So I have a very long table with about 5000 or 6000 columns which contain my values but I'm not sure which is the right way to extract it in a easy way to perform some analysis. The table has about 600 rows.

I have written a report function in python with the help of pandas. The format I can already analyse is like the following:

```
Time;SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD
11:12:123456;12345678;5.3;53.4;53;-36.6;
11:12:123457;12345679;5.5;55;54;-40;
```

So the time is slightly different and the Sensor ID will be different.
I use groupby(SensorID) and plots of the groupby and after that I perform some value_count() within some columns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, each data line in the CSV contains `ValueA - D` for a set sensors, sharting the same `ID` and `Time` columns. Also your dataline ends with a semicolon which will throw pandas off.

```
[...]92345670;5.9;60.4;55;-33.6;
```

This answer leaves the semicolon stays in place since I assume you can change the process that produces the CSV file.

```
from io import StringIO

string = """
ID;Time;SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD;SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD;SensorID;ValueA;ValueB;ValueC;ValueD;
11234;11:12:123456;12345678;5.3;53.4;53;-36.6;72345670;5.8;57.4;56;-39.6;92345670;5.9;60.4;55;-33.6;
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep=';', engine='python')

# Shift the columns. We need this because the extra semicolon!
columns = df.columns[1:]
df = df.iloc[:, :-1]
df.columns = columns
df = df.set_index('Time')

# n is how many groups of sensor measurement are stored in each line
n = df.shape[1] // 5
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(n), ['SensorID', 'ValueA', 'ValueB', 'ValueC', 'ValueD']])
result = df.stack(level=0).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
           Time  SensorID  ValueA  ValueB  ValueC  ValueD
0  11:12:123456  12345678     5.3    53.4      53   -36.6
1  11:12:123456  72345670     5.8    57.4      56   -39.6
2  11:12:123456  92345670     5.9    60.4      55   -33.6
```

Now you can send it to your analysis function.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for thinking about it. Have you tested this code? I'm getting this table as output:

```
Time    0
0   11234   11:12:123456
1   11234   12345678
2   11234   5.3
3   11234   53.4
4   11234   53
5   11234   -36.6
6   11234   72345670
7   11234   5.8
8   11234   57.4
9   11234   56
10  11234   -39.6
11  11234   92345670
12  11234   5.9
13  11234   60.4
14  11234   55
15  11234   -33.6
```